# Making custom cell with JSQMessagesViewController - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Hello I am using the [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) library and I am trying to add a view below the avatar image. I have read the FAQ and the Documentation and done everything according to the [instructions](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1739) but it still doesn't seem to work. Can you please help me out?

I have created 3 custom classes, subclasses of the classes:

- JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
- JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming
- JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing

ChatCell, sublcass of the JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

```
@interface QChatCell : JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

@end
@implementation QChatCell

@end
```

ChatCellIncoming, subclass of the ChatCell. I have created a xib file (QChatCellIncoming.xib) for this as well which is a copy of the JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming xib file:

```
@interface QChatCellIncoming : QChatCell

@end

@implementation QChatCellIncoming

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self.messageBubbleTopLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [self.cellBottomLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
}

+ (UINib *)nib {
    return [UINib nibWithNibName:@"QChatCellIncoming" bundle:nil];
}

+ (NSString *)cellReuseIdentifier {
    return @"QChatCellIncoming";
}
@end
```

ChatCellOutgoing, subclass of the ChatCell. I have created a xib file (QChatCellOutgoing.xib) for this as well which is a copy of the JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing xib file:

```
@interface QChatCellOutgoing : QChatCell

@end

@implementation QChatCellOutgoing

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self.messageBubbleTopLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    [self.cellBottomLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
}

+ (UINib *)nib {
    return [UINib nibWithNibName:@"QChatCellOutgoing" bundle:nil];
}

+ (NSString *)cellReuseIdentifier {
    return @"QChatCellOutgoing";
}
@end
```

In the Chat Controller Class in View Did Load I do this:

```
self.outgoingCellIdentifier = [QChatCellOutgoing cellReuseIdentifier];
self.outgoingMediaCellIdentifier = [QChatCellOutgoing mediaCellReuseIdentifier];

[self.collectionView registerNib:[QChatCellOutgoing nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.outgoingCellIdentifier];
[self.collectionView registerNib:[QChatCellOutgoing nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.outgoingMediaCellIdentifier];

self.incomingCellIdentifier = [QChatCellIncoming cellReuseIdentifier];
self.incomingMediaCellIdentifier = [QChatCellIncoming mediaCellReuseIdentifier];

[self.collectionView registerNib:[QChatCellIncoming nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.incomingCellIdentifier];
[self.collectionView registerNib:[QChatCellIncoming nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.
```

incomingMediaCellIdentifier];

And in the cellForItemAtIndexPath function Ive done this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell;

    if ([self incoming:messages[indexPath.item]]) {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.incomingCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.textView setTextColor:COLOR_CHAT_INCOMING_TEXT];
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.outgoingCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.textView setTextColor:COLOR_CHAT_OUTGOING_TEXT];
        return cell;
    } 
}
```

When I go to the chat screen, the app crashes with the following error:

```
Unknown class _TtC5Q_Fix17QChatCellOutgoing in Interface Builder file.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UICollectionViewCell 0x7f821cd42a80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key avatarContainerView.'
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of your issue is in storyboard. Something points to a non existing class named `_TtC5Q_Fix17QChatCellOutgoing`.

To not have to manually click through all objects in your storyboard:

- Open the `storyBoardName.storyboard` file in a text editor of your choice
- Search for`TtC5Q_Fix17QChatCellOutgoing`
- If you get no results, search `avatarContainerView`

You will hopefully find something like:

```
`customClass="TtC5Q_Fix17QChatCellOutgoing"`
```

within a nested structure that should give you a good hint where to dig in in storyboard .

Comment: There is no customClass="TtC5Q_Fix17QChatCellOutgoing". The same happens for the ChatCellIncoming too.

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue is probaby rooted in this  ChatCellIncoming, subclass of the ChatCell. I have created a xib file (QChatCellIncoming.xib) for this as well which is a copy of the JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming xib file: By doing that ie (copying the file) You may have missed changing the Class. I have made this mistake many times before and the error message is quite misleading. 
So if you open up Xcode and open your QChatCellIncoming.xib select the cell itself in the interface builder

[image: interface builder]

Then look at the right panel IE(Utilities Panel) select the "identity Inspector" looks like this: screen shot

[image: identity Inspector]

And Change your class from JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming

[image]

To your class name QChatCellIncoming Now your UI knows which code is backing it and doesn't get confused .  Then clean and run and it should solve that issue.  Let me know if you have more issues .